# Simple regular expression for digit and word match

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match the following pattern using regular expression:

```
Something-23432
```

I am using following code to find it using regular expression

```
preg_match('/^Something\-/[0-9/]+/', $msg, $matches);
```

It's not working :/. Any help would be appreciated!

There would be only one occurrence of above mentioned PATTERN in the whole document.

### Edit

```
<?php

preg_match('/^Something\-[0-9]+$/', "I am looking for Something-2343. I am not sure if this script can find it.", $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

This code just generates

```
Array ( )
```

Comment: you need to be more precise in what you are matching. ie will this always be the same word, hyphen and changing number? or all possible different? Etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your line to : `preg_match('/^Something\-[0-9]+$/', $msg, $matches);`

```
<?php
    $msg="Something-23432";

    if( preg_match('/^Something\-[0-9]+$/', $msg, $matches)) {
           echo 'found';
            }
    else {
              echo "Not found";
            }

    print_r($matches);

?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
found Array ( [0] => Something-23432 )
```

Comment: @Tweet Did you copy/paste FaceOfJock's regex?  Looks like you have an extra character in the first argument :)

Comment: Danronmoon, Thanks for pointing this out. However, it does not return anything.

Comment: @Tweet Remove `^` and `$` from the regex.  They match the start/end of the string and you have your match in the middle.

Comment: i tested it in my local, and it works i edit my answer check it

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/Something\-[0-9]+/', $msg, $matches);
```

If you wanted five characters specifically,

```
preg_match('/Something\-[0-9]{5}/', $msg, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. However, it gives the following error: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in

Comment: Fixed, just forgot the PHP slashes.

Comment: I thought you were matching a single string. To allow it to do an embedded match, simply remove the first and last characters from between the slashes; `^` denotes a start of string, and `$` denotes an end of string.